# Java - Make corners of JWindow 100% transparent on MacOS (Snow leopard)

Tags: java, macos, swing, transparency, osx-snow-leopard

I am trying to make a small java application, and I need the corners of a JWindow to be 'cut' off, in a 45 degree angle.

I have tried using the AWTUtilities.setWindowShape, but apparently it is not supported by MacOS (snow leopard).

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?? Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: Another Java developer ignoring the HIG…sigh.

Comment: Is there such component JWindow? I know Window and JFrame.

Comment: Anyway, you can checkout about overriding the paintComponent method (for swing components).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[How to Create Translucent and Shaped Windows](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/GUI/translucent_shaped_windows/)

The link above should help you a lot, I used that tutorial once before.  Made by Sun!